# Installing Address module on Drupal 8

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I have been struggling with this now for 2 days and cannot get past trying to enable the address module as I just get the error message "Address requires the commerceguys/addressing library."

Documentation seems a bit unclear how to enable this, and even the documentation page returns a 404 error. I have followed the README.me file in the address module but still just getting the same error.

My Steps:
1.) Download Address module, unzip and add to /modules
2.) Enable in the D8 extend page, message returned "Address requires the commerceguys/addressing library"

I then download and unzip the library from the git page https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing, this unzips a directory called addressing-master

Now I'm not sure where I should put this folder. do I make a '/libraries' folder and put it in there? Do I put it in '/vendor'?
I tried both the above and re attempted to enable the address module but still got the same message returned "Address requires the commerceguys/addressing library."

So I have installed composer manager, run init.php from the command line, all good, went to enable the address module and still got that same message.

I then try cd into the address module directory in terminal then run $ composer install, still got that same message.
Now I try adding "commerceguys/addressing": "dev-master" to the require part of the composer.json file that's in the root directory then running composer drupal-update from the root of my project and I get this:

> Drupal\composer_manager\Composer\Command::update
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   - Updating jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver dev-master (10d7c48 => 5bf53fa)

[RuntimeException]
The .git directory is missing from /Users/barrypoore/mampsites/d8/vendor/jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for m
ore information

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--] [
]...

I have googled as much as I can to try to resolve this but 2 days now and I'm still stuck with no address module enabled, can somebody please advise?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your problem is a Drupal core issue with the `jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver` package that they've fixed in 8.0.x-dev:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2629772

I couldn't get their patch to apply cleanly but when I manually made the changes, I was able to run `drupal-update` and install the Address module.